# How to append values to hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a one field which is hidden and that gets added dynamically to track the another select box's selected items.

for e.g:

```
    hidden_field_name= count_select;

    select_box_name = select1;
```

both gets added dynamically when user click "add" button. Now I want to store the select1's selected item count in count_select for every instance.

But when I use the val() method it write the total click's in count_select value.

Here is code:

Html code :

```js
function getCount() {
  top.count = $("select.container_countable option:selected[value!='']").length;
  $('.countable').val(top.count);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='hidden' class='countable' id='count_containerfilter' name='countable_cont' value=0>
<select onclick='getCount()' class='container_countable' multiple='multiple' name='new_containerfilter'>
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: It would be better if you post your markup as well as js codes.

Comment: Can you plz show some of your code?

Comment: There is no JavaScript function `val()`, I guess you are using jQuery.

Comment: @NabilKadimi Yes right I am using Jquery !!! And Sorry I have no experience with this.

Comment: what I want to achieve is : select_box = 2 item selected ,newly added select box = 3 item selected , so finally count_select should contain count_select = [2, 3] instead of that it contains [5, 5]

Comment: your SELECT box HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [this comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010666/how-to-append-values-to-hidden-field/27011059#comment42548563_27010666):

> what I want to achieve is : select_box = 2 item selected ,newly added
>   select box = 3 item selected , so finally count_select should contain
>   count_select = [2, 3]....

You could use an array to track the selections. Once done, either assign that array directly to the `hidden` `input` or `stringify` it and assign the string.

***See this snippet:***

```js
var tmp = [];
$("select.countable").on("change", function() {
    tmp = [];
    $("select.countable").each(function() {
        var ctr = $(this).find("option:selected").length;
        tmp.push(ctr);
    });
    $("#ctr").val(JSON.stringify(tmp));
    $("#result").text($("#ctr").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='hidden' id='ctr' />
<hr/>
<select class="countable" multiple>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<select class="countable" multiple>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<hr/>
<p id="result"></p>
```

*Here is a fiddle for you to play with: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/f6o3ped8/1/***

Try adding more `select`s and see the result.

.

Comment: This is what I wanted. But I tried to embed this code in my code and it is not working. As I am adding the table content through the script code. but it is not listening to the on change event.

Comment: In that case use event delegation. i.e. bind an event on parent and check `target`. e.g. `$(parent).on("change", ".countable", func...`. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/n1238LLo/1/

Comment: @Sagar: BTW, it would make your life easier if you do not `stringify` the array. Just assign it as is. This way on the server-side you will get a comma-separated string which you can split easily.

Answer (score 0):

[This code is from jQuery docs for `:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) (with slight modification):

```js
$("select")
  .change(function() {
    var count = $("select option:selected").length; // Count selected
    $("input").val(count);                          // Update field
  })
  .trigger("change");                               // Trigger at least once
```

```css
select{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option>Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option selected="selected">Dirt</option>
</select>
<input />
```

Comment: I don't think so this will work out for me. This is the same situation in which I am right now . When I submit the form querydict contains the input as a dict key and values will be [first+second selected items, first+second selected items]